# Hide Chart label in apex:gaugeseries

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-charting, gaugeseries

how could I hide the chart labels in  chart, I'm tring with apex:chartLabel display="none" but seems not working.
My code:

```
<apex:page controller="GaugeChartController">
  <style>
        .myFormStyle {
            background-color: #EEF1F6;
        }
    </style>
<div class="myFormStyle">  
<apex:chart height="250" width="450" animate="true" data="{!data}" legend="false">
<apex:axis type="Gauge" position="gauge" 
   minimum="0" maximum="100" steps="10">
</apex:axis>

<apex:gaugeSeries dataField="score" donut="80" 
    colorSet="#0074d9,#001f3f">    
<apex:chartLabel display="none"/>   
</apex:gaugeSeries> 
</apex:chart>   
</div>  
</apex:page>
```

the chart result:
[image]

EDIT
Is it possible to add a red indicator like the image below?
[image]

Comment: Do you want to hide those numbers 10,20,30..?

Comment: Yes, if it's possible I want to show only 3 Value 0-50-100

Comment: Where is red indicator? Are you talking about the black one?

Comment: the black one yes sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These numbers are coming from `<apex:axis` and there is no documentation available to update the style in the standard way. Refer to this SFSE [link](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/34354/vf-radar-chart-labels-clipped), you can use jQuery to hide the labels as described by Keith Clarke.

If you check the browser developer console you will find that all these numbers present inside a `tspan` HTML element for Gauge Series. You can get all the elements through jQuery and change the CSS display property to none and the elements will be removed from the page.

```
<apex:page controller="DonutChartController" title="Gauge Chart">
    <apex:includeScript value="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"/>
    <apex:chart height="350" width="450" data="{!pieData}" theme="Salesforce" legend="false" >
        <apex:legend position="top" spacing="20" rendered="false"/>
        <apex:axis type="Gauge" position="top" minimum="500" maximum="1500"  >
            <apex:chartLabel display="none" color="#FF0000"  />
        </apex:axis>
        <apex:gaugeSeries dataField="caseCount" donut="55"  labelField="caseType" >
            <apex:chartLabel display="none" color="#FF0000"  />
        </apex:gaugeSeries>
    </apex:chart>
<script>
var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
j$(document).ready(function() {
    var updateSvgCss = function() {
       var tspan = j$('tspan');        
       if (tspan.length > 0) {
           tspan.each(function(){
                if(j$(this).text()!='0' && j$(this).text()!='50' && j$(this).text()!='100'){
                    j$(this).css('display', 'none');
                }
           });
       } else {
           // svg element appears to be dyamically inserted so poll for it
           setTimeout(updateSvgCss, 10);
       }
    };
    updateSvgCss();
});
</script>    
</apex:page>
```

Comment: I have updated the code to show only 0-50-100. You can update for any other value you want.

Comment: Work like a charm thank you. One last question there it's possible to add a red indicator using visualforce or jquery just like a standard gauge dashboard?

Comment: @L.benedettini If this answer has solved your question you can use the check mark next to it to mark it as such. That will help others who are looking at it to locate the accepted solution. Regarding red indicator, I can give a try. If possible please update the Question with an image of the chart you are looking for.

Comment: thanl you Saroy, you are very kind. I edit my post whit an image of the indicator like you said